# Is there always a way to alphanumerically name something, so that it is ordered between two given places in a list?

Tags: sorting

What I mean is… Say you have files called 4A, 4B and 4C. If I want to make a file that would, if alphanumerically sorted, placed between 4A and 4B?

Comment: Is your question "what is between two things that are next to each other?"

Comment: Yeah, you can name it 4A* where the star is any character or string.

Comment: If the existing files were `4A`, `4AA`, `4C`, the answer is not quite as clear: you need `4A0`, say, and if was to avoid `4A0` you start to have an issue :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The critical word in the question is "always".   This means (I assume) "for any set of file names (strings)".  Not just two-letter ones.

I first answered "Yes", because it seems like you can always add a letter to make a string between any two given strings.

However, the answer is actually "No".

In this "alphanumeric" sequence, there genuinely is a "next element" for each element, and you can't place something between an element and it's next element.

For example, the next element after "4a" is "4a0"

There is no string alphanumerically between "4a" and "4a0"

---

Supplement:

The question implies that the alphabet for file names is "alphanumeric", which means [0..9a..zA..Z], and the sorting has to be alphanumeric (as normally defined).   In this case, the answer (as stated above) is "No".

However, as described in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978970/is-there-a-sequence-of-strings-where-there-is-always-an-element-between-any-two/978980#978980 if you control the way that you sort the strings (file names) you can define a way of sorting that guarantees that there is always a string that can go between two others.

If, in addition, you control the alphabet (so you could choose to name the files only with [0..9] in the name for example) then it becomes quite easy.

Comment: I thought so. Now I'm sad :(

Comment: I edited my answer to be careful to only talk about the alphanumeric sequence.   You could ask over at maths.stackexchange.com whether there is some sorting algorithm (or other cunning algorithm) that could deliver the result you want.   Those guys are clever with infinity and algorithms and stuff :)  If you do, post a link here, I'm curious.

Comment: What the heck.  I asked myself.   The answer is "yes, you can do it".   Now you just have to understand what those mathemeticians are talking about to do it in practice! :) :D   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978970/is-there-a-sequence-of-strings-where-there-is-always-an-element-between-any-two/978980#978980

Comment: That is way too advanced for me, I'm a simply hobby scripter/programmer who prefers writing prose. But thank you very much for your help! :)